# How could replace from the PHP String

Tags: php, regex

I wan't to replace

```
[a href='url']link[/a]
```

to

```
<a href='url'>link</a>
```

I am using `$line = str_replace("[a href='+(.*)+']", "<a href='+(.*)+' >", $line);` is not working.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to use a regular expression to do this

```
$line = preg_replace('~\\[a +href=\'([^\']+)\'\\]([^\\[]+)\\[/a\\]~', '<a href="$1">$2</a>', $line);
```

Comment: "You have to use a regular expression" No, you don't have to.

Comment: if he simply want to do this, this is the fastest way - sure, you could something different

Comment: Well... once you get to nested tags, you most likely would want to. Of course it's not like you really need to... you can just as well write a compiler.

Comment: @Philipp can you also tell me, the syntax for the same work in javascript??

Comment: try `newval = varname.replace(/\[a +href='([^']+)'\]([^\[]+)\[\/a\]/, '<a href="$1">$2</a>')`

Answer (score 7):

Why not just use:

```
$search = array('[', ']');
$replace = array('<', '>');

$line = str_replace($search, $replace, $line);
```

Comment: Will work for simple cases. Once you get `[]` in the `url` or `link` it'll fail (by replacing too much)

Comment: You're right, but the OP asked for a specific usecase. If he really only needs to do that this approach might be easier to read than a regex.

Comment: Sure. Your answer is in fact correct, just limited to simple case (which might be enough for what OP needs).

Answer (score 1):

simply use

```
$string = str_replace(array('[', ']'), array('<', '>'), $string);
```

Answer (score 0):

This is a great tutorial http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=x9VLWlQhNtM it shows you how to make a small templating engine and it covers what your asking

Answer (score 0):

Try this :

```
$str = "[a href='url']link[/a]";
$new_str  = preg_replace('/\[a href=\'(.*)\'\](.*)\[\/a\]/','<a href=\'$1\'>$2</a>',$str);
echo $new_str;
```